# Can't successfully run a selenium test in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I can't run my first Selenium test in Eclipse.

I'm pretty sure that all the configurations are OK.

You can see my class + the exception in the screenshot below:

http://s12.postimg.org/ik0wqb2f1/2015_02_08_1725.png

Please your assistance.

Thanks a lot,

Idan.

Comment: New There another exception after running:
Error: Main method not found in class selenium.myClass, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you haven't set up your project correctly.  Right click on your project, then go to:

--> Build path...-->Configure build path...

Once there, go to the Libraries tab, and remove that giant list of .jar files.

Since **System** and **String** are not resolving, it looks like you are missing the JRE System Library, so press [Add Library...] and add it.

Then, for you Selenium setup, just press [Add External JARs...] and add only:

- selenium-java-2.44.0.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar

And see if you are able to run it after that.

Comment: Thanks, From when I can download the JARs of "system" & "string"?  @weems74

Comment: Those are in the JRE System Library I mentioned above.  If you aren't seeing the JRE System Library in your Eclipse libraries, you may need to install the JDK correctly on your system.  Here's a link with instructions for [Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html), [Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html) , and [Linux](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Test NG plugin for Eclipse, you can download from here:

[Test NG plugin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse)

And don't forget to add the Maven dependency to your project too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Probably you also need some of the following libraries. If they are needed  could be added by Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.50.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finally, when creating your test, set the gecko driver property and @Test annotation from **org.testng.annotations.Test**

```
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverLocation);
}

@Test
public void myTest() {

    driver.get("https://myRUL/home");
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. There is some problem with your package. 
Try creating new project and import jars correctly by following steps in the link below.

http://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but I still receive an exception on console :/

Comment: Are you able to run Simple "hello world' program?
There is problem with your package or propably with java. 
Try uninstalling and reinstalling java. Then delete existing workspace and create a new one. then try